# Add number in a bash script

Tags: bash

I have a folder containing file `file1.png`, `file2.png`, ..., `file5.png`. I'd like to copy them into a new folder and rename them as `file6.png` to `file10.png`. The bash script I used was:

```
for i in `seq 1 5`;
k=$((i+5));
do cp src/file$i.png dst/file$k.png;
done;
```

However, the line `k=$((i+5))` always says `syntax error`. Any ideas?

Comment: `do` should come before `k=$((i+5))`

Comment: http://www.shellcheck.net/# helps in such cases...

Comment: As written, the semi-colons are totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 4):

Below script do the job :

```
for i in {1..5}
do # You need to put 'do' just after the for statement
cp src/file"$i".png dst/file"$((i+5))".png
done
```

---

**Notes**

- See [[ brace expansion ]](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace#ranges) to know more about `{START..END}`.
- Note `$((i+5))` returns the result to where it is called from, so you may avoid using the intermediate variable `k`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this-

```
for i in `seq 1 5`
do
k=$(($i+5))
cp src/file"$i".png dst/file"$k".png
done
```

Comment: No harm omitting `$` inside `((..))`.

Comment: As written, the semi-colons are totally unnecessary.

Comment: @user3439894, yup you're right. I was lazy during my copy pasting. I changed a one liner to a multi line comment for greater readability. Removed the semi colons now.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `do` after the `for`:

```
for i in `seq 1 5`; do k=$((i+5)); echo $k; done;
#output:         ---^---
6
7
8
9
10
```